# Exporting the Google Street View coverage layer?

Tags: geojson, google-maps, google-street-view

How can I export the coverage layer of Google Street View (the blueish layer that appears when dragging the pegman on Google Maps) to (for example) GeoJSON format to work with it in different places?

Comment: Which GIS software?

Comment: @Mapperz I want to use it here: maphub.net